# How to correctly relay TCP traffic between sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, portforwarding

I'm trying to write some Python code that will establish an invisible relay between two TCP sockets. My current technique is to set up two threads, each one reading and subsequently writing 1kb of data at a time in a particular direction (i.e. 1 thread for A to B, 1 thread for B to A).

This works for some applications and protocols, but it isn't foolproof - sometimes particular applications will behave differently when running through this Python-based relay. Some even crash.

I think that this is because when I finish performing a read on socket A, the program running there considers its data to have already arrived at B, when in fact I - the devious man in the middle - have yet to send it to B. In a situation where B isn't ready to receive the data (whereby `send()` blocks for a while), we are now in a state where A believes it has successfully sent data to B, yet I am still holding the data, waiting for the `send()` call to execute. I think this is the cause of the difference in behaviour that I've found in some applications, while using my current relaying code. Have I missed something, or does that sound correct?

If so, my real question is: is there a way around this problem? Is it possible to only read from socket A when we know that B is ready to receive data? Or is there another technique that I can use to establish a truly 'invisible' two-way relay between [already open & established] TCP sockets?

Comment: You say you're using TCP sockets, but you commented further down you're using "Unix" sockets. Are you really using Unix domain sockets?

Comment: Yes, mixed up two different questions. I've marked the correct answer below as the one which answers the question I actually posted. Still stuck with my Unix socket relaying problem though... :(

Comment: How are you handling connection termination? Are you aware that the connection can be closed in the `A -> B` direction, but still be open in the `B -> A` direction? Does your proxy properly pass this on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to only read from
>   socket A when we know that B is ready
>   to receive data?

Sure: use [select.select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html?highlight=select#select.select) on both sockets A and B (if it returns saying only one of them is ready, use it on the other one), and only read from A and write to B when you know they're both ready.  E.g.:

```
import select

def fromAtoB(A, B):
    r, w = select.select([A], [B], [])
    if not r: select.select([A], [], [])
    elif not w: select.select([], [B], [])
    B.sendall(A.recv(4096))
```

Comment: I've changed my code to use this, but the original problem is still there - the app I'm testing with still behaves differently with a relay in place. Also, putting this in a while loop causes Python to use a lot of CPU cycles. I should note that the data is being sent with fairly high throughput. If you have any other suggestions I'd love to hear them.

Comment: I've fixed the CPU issue but still no dice on my original problem. Here's my code: http://pastie.org/910900

Comment: (1) I'm surprised to hear about the high CPU consumption, since my code doesn't spend any until the data's ready -- maybe data's being sent in tiny packets, but even then, if you want to relay it very promptly, it's hard to think how to improve this (unless you're willing to add, potentially, very long latencies).  (2) I'm not surprised that this has little to do with your actual problem -- I just answered the question of yours that I quoted, about reading from A only when we know B is ready for writing; behavior differences may be due to A checking its peer, which you can't fake.

Comment: Indeed; but I'm actually working with UNIX sockets and there's no way to check their legitimacy, as far as I know. I move the original socket to a safe location before creating my own fake one in its place. Truly baffled by this!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's likely to be your problem.

In general, the sending application can't tell when the receiving application actually calls recv() to read the data: the sender's send() may have completed, but the TCP implementations in the source & destination OS will be doing buffering, flow control, retransmission, etc.

Even without your relay in the middle, the only way for A to "consider its data to have already arrived at B" is to receive a response from B saying "yep, I got it".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the application you're proxying is poorly written.

For instance, if I call `recv(fd, buf, 4096, 0);` I'm not promised 4096 bytes.  The system makes a best-effort to provide it.

If 1k isn't a multiple of your application's `recv` or `send` sizes, and the application is broken, then grouping the data sent into 1k blocks will break the app.

Comment: I see. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Encourage the application writer to write better software.

If you're trying to make a generic proxy, then no, there isn't.  If it is for a particular application, try emulating the size of send and recv used by the client and server.